# Maintain dtypes when storing dataframes into libraries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the present data-frame

[image: db_test]

If I store this data-frame in a library

```
store.initialize_library('Test_Library', lib_type='TickStoreV3')
lib_test = store.get_library('Test_Library')
lib_test.write('2015', db_test)
df_test_rd = lib_test.read('2015', date_range=DateRange('2013-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
```

all data are for unknown reasons converted into strings

[image: df_test_rd]

Can someone suggest me how to maintain the correct dtypes?